# Mapping a matplotlib plot to a variable

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, variables

I was wondering if it were possible to save a matplotlib plot to a variable, and only have it called when you call on the variable.

With this code for example, I cannot figure out how to save graph 'a' into a variable without printing it when the function main() is called. The goal is to not run it when the function is called, but call it as a variable later. Thank you for any help!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# an example graph type
def fig_barh(ylabels, xvalues, title=''):
    # create a new figure
    fig = plt.figure()

    # plot to it
    yvalues = 0.1 + np.arange(len(ylabels))
    plt.barh(yvalues, xvalues, figure=fig)
    yvalues += 0.4
    plt.yticks(yvalues, ylabels, figure=fig)
    if title:
        plt.title(title, figure=fig)

    # return it
    return fig

def main():
    a = fig_barh(['a','b','c'], [1, 2, 3], 'Test #1')
```